# retrieving text in correct format

Tags: vb.net

I'm wondering in figuring out, how to send emial on click of button in vb.net in defined format with some links.
Currently my status is: I created a dropdown which load the list of some codes from sql.
In sql i have created a table which maintains code and emailBody. Now when  I Select some code in the dropdown and click on the  "button".  I wants to retrieve the emailBody  associated  with the code in the same format  which i Have in sql. currently I'm able to retrieve the emialBody but it is sending as paragraph  when I check the email. But while bebugging  dataset xml view is in correct format.

and also how  to add links to the text in sql?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code parts? What do you mean by links? Do you mean Hyperlinks like `http://mysite.com/Index.html`?

Comment: the EmialBody Text  has hyperlink like " view my Website". this email is coming from sql server

Comment: What do you mean, when you say "the email is coming from sql server"? Do you mean the email body text? In which format is it stored in your database? RTF, XML, just plain text or what else? Show us the code that you use to create and send the email.

Comment: I have inserted into the table maually like:

Comment: I have inserted into the table maually like:                     insert into emiatable(code, emialbody)values('At4','this is the email huge text about 15 lines which will be the body of the email and I do have some hyperlinks in it ') . I think this is normal plain text. I'm retrieving from the dataset DS.table(0).rows(0).item("emialbody") and assigned to string . passing this string to smtp mail

Comment: It is called e-mail (like electronic mail). The relevant code is not the database code, but the code, which creates and sends the email. I do not know any method, which allows inserting hyperlinks in the email body. You will have to insert the address as plain text. Email programs like Outlook usually do automatically format these addresses as hyperlinks that are clickable. However, the address will be visible. You cannot replace it by an alias like “My Website”.

Answer (score 0):

[You will want to send an html email.](http://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/vbnet.aspx?cat=6)

```
    Dim client as SmtpClient
    Dim Email As New SmtpMail("")
    Dim Server As New SmtpServer("")
    Email.From = ""
    Email.To = ""
    Email.Subject = ""
    Email.HtmlBody = "<a href="www.website.com">Text</a>"
    Email.User = ""
    Email.Password = ""

    If server SSL
    SmtpMail.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto

    client.SendMail(Server, EMail)
```

[Using MailDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.aspx) you can insert some dynamic variables as well.